# List directories containing Unicode characters on Windows

Tags: php, windows, unicode, directory

I am using Windows 2003 to write some PHP code. I use XAMPP Portable (copy to D:). The problem:

```
$path = 'D:\ebooks';
$all_file = scandir($path);
foreach ($all_file as $file) {
  if (is_dir("$path/$file") && $file != '.' && $file != '..') {
    echo $file . "<br />\n";
  }
}
```

When I call the script (with browser), I didn't see any directories (within D:\ebooks) containing a Unicode character (I tested with Vietnamese, Japanese, Chinese, Czech).

But if I remove **`is_dir("$path/$file")`**, the directories display with many strange characters and many `???` characters.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode name" ?  you mean special characters like Ô or ü ?

Comment: The "many strange characters" part is possibly related to your encoding of the browser output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of bugs related to PHP access to a windows filesystem. While Windows does store the filenames as UTF-16, PHP's internals use the much older ANSI api's. So it's best to only do stuff with filenames that are in the ascii range, or switch to a different operating system.

Comment: @cbuckley: Normally I'd discourage people from saying that, but in this case it's just fact that PHP on windows has really shitty filesystem support.

Comment: i have this problem in linux php 7.1. please check link: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74958

Answer (score 0):

This might help with the Czech, it won't help with CJK (still looking for that myself). 
Buggy "Rationale": UTF-8 is ok, as long as it's mappable to the windows character set.

PHP is unpleasantly clear about this:

> scandir() and readdir() do not support Unicode filenames
>
> http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34574
>
> «PHP does not support unicode operations until PHP6.»

written in September 2005.

You could also try to grab the [dos short name equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324041/how-does-windows-determine-handle-the-dos-short-name-of-any-given-file) by using system('dir /X'), parse the results for short and long names and work from there. Display long names, actually accessing (for stat, timestamp and file open of course) with the short names...