# PHP file handling

Tags: php

I have created a folder and named it "↓" (using Alt+25). My operating System is Windows XP service pack 3.
Now,
I want to write a file in it with filename `rpa.txt`

```
<?php
$file='C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\↓\rpa.txt';
fopen($file,'w');
?>
```

Problem is: after this code is executed, the file `rpa.txt` should be created automatically in the folder named '↓', but that doesn't happen.

Comment: Do you receive any kind of error message?

Comment: print the output of file_exists('C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\↓\'); I am pretty sure that PHP is having difficulties reading ↓ character in the name...

Comment: @Bjoern  NO! the file should be created after the code execution :( . No error messages!! I'm facing this problem only when i use special charecters like ↓ ,¢ etc. for my folder name.

Comment: What codepage is your Windows filesystem; what charset are you using for your PHP script? Do they match? This is a good reason to only use ASCII characters in file and directory names

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10008491/1216680)

Comment: Well.. I just found out that (alt+25) is one of the ASCII CONTROL CHARECTERS. Using 'ASCII CONTROL CHARECTERS' or 'EXTENED ASCII CHARECTERS' for folder name are resulting in failure of creating the file "rpa.txt" in that particular folder. The file "rpa.txt" is created only if we use ASCII PRINTABLE CHARECTERS for folder name (excluding \/:*?"<>|).